# How to replace "\\" to "\" C#

Tags: c#

Here is an example: `"\\\r\\\n\\\u003c"`

Expected Result: `"\r\n\u003c"`

I have tried `string.Replace(@"\\\", @"\");`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `\n`, `\r` and `\u003c` are string representations of chars. Each of them is not a string but a single char. I'm not sure what you want to do but you should know that.

Comment: @Theraot - Didn't understand what you intend to say! Would you mind to rephrase?

Comment: It looks to me like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP could be trying to replace backslashes, but actually, the string already would look like "\r\n\u003c" beause the backslashed are escaped ("\\"). Now, perhaps OP does not really want "\r\n\u003c" but new line followed by "<", then that is parsing escape sequences, which is a different problem entirely. Just [adding more backslashes looks doomed to fail from my perspective](https://www.xkcd.com/1638/).

Comment: @Theraot - Oops, I used `@` while escaping, my bad. Now I understood your point too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.Unescape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx) method for this approach. It will replace all double `\\` with `\`.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell since you don't show your exact code, but possibly you're not saving the result of your `string.Replace()`.  Your code looks good.

The `@` symbol in front of your literal strings make them verbatim literal strings, and therefore prevents the backslashes from being uses as escape characters, which is what you want here.

`string.Replace()` doesn't modify the input string, but rather it returns the modified string.  Perhaps you're not using the return value from `string.Replace()`.

The following code works:

```
var stringWithDoubleSlashes = @"\\r\\n\\u003c";

var stringWithSingleSlashes = stringWithDoubleSlashes.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
Console.WriteLine(stringWithSingleSlashes); // displays \r\n\u003c
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the full char `\\n` to `\n`. Your way does't work because a backslash is used to escape charachters.